# Is it safe to use printf("%*s", len, ptr) where len is an integer and ptr is non-null terminated?

Tags: c, printf

Is it safe to use printf("%*s", len, ptr) where len is an integer and ptr is non-null terminated?
If not safe, what will happen in the worst case?
And then how can I make it safe?

thank you

Comment: I think you actually meant to ask about `"%.*s"`  the sometimes cryptic format string syntax of printf is viewed by some as a danger itself.

Answer (score 1):

No not safe at all. `"%*s"` only sets a minimum display width, it does not enforce input string length at all.

But assuming you actually mean `"%.*s"`

Yes, that would be safe.

This format of `printf` does not look at `char`s in/at `ptr` past the *n<sub>th</sub>* (index n-1)

So assuming that `n` holds an appropriate value there will be no access outside of the allocation unit of `ptr` and thus no risk of out-of-range pointer undefined behaviour.